# Exception when using multiple constructors with Mvvm light and ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm facing this issue when having a `ViewModel` with multiple constructors in Mvvm Light:

I have a view model that has an empty ctor, and then i created a second one that receives a parameter (wanting to do something else in some cases ... ).
If i try to run the application I'll get:

*Cannot register: Multiple constructors found in Inner_VM but none marked with PreferredConstructor.*

This happens only if i register the `ViewModel` in the `Locator`:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Inner_VM>();
```

and then use this in the property:

```
public Inner_VM Inner
{
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Inner_VM>(); }
}
```

If I omit the registration of the `ViewModel`, and then use this in the property:

```
public Inner_VM Inner
{
    get { return new Inner_VM(); }
}
```

everything seems to work ...

I thought the first option makes use of a static instance that is being reused, and the second just creates a new one everytime I use it. (it doesn't matter much in my app, but I'm trying to understand the why, and couldn't find anything to explain it, even after searching both S.O. & google for this issue).

Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 12):

you can put `PreferredConstructorAttribute` on your Default constructor to solve this issue.

Comment: Tried that, but then every time someone calls that viewmodel, that constructor gets called ... 
([PreferredConstructor]  on top of ctor, seems to be the same as PreferredConstructorAttribute ...)

Answer (score -2):

This change nothing:

```
Public Class PreferredConstructorAttribute : Inherits Attribute
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class tblFiltresChamps
    Public Sub New() ' Le JsonToObject a besoin d'un constructeur sans paramètres
        items = New BindingList(Of tblFiltreChamps)()
    End Sub
    <PreferredConstructor>
    Public Sub New(Env As SqiD23.Env)
        Me.New()
        _Env = Env
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, i'm bloqued too, but the Nitin answer don't solve the problem. the "PreferredConstructor" attribute change nothing.
I use the mvvm Light on Framework4

Comment: then you could have just upvoted my comment saying it doesn't help :)

Comment: Okay, but maybe I'm missing something. It's to move the conversation forward

Comment: :) ... not sure adding answers that don't answer the question moves it forward. TBH, it might not even be an issue with newer versions. worth checking though...  will try to find some time for it on the weekend ...